# BQ Array compare from one row to rest of all rows

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, difference

I have a table in BQ

```
    WITH tbl_campaign_ipmapping AS
(
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign1' as campaign,  ['10.0.0.0','20.0.0.0','30.0.0.0', '40.0.0.0'] AS ip_array UNION ALL
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign2' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '20.0.0.0', '50.0.0.0']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign3' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '40.0.0.0', '60.0.0.0', '70.0.0.0', '80.0.0.0']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign4' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '20.0.0.0', '30.0.0.0'] UNION ALL 
  
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign1' ,  ['10.1.1.1','20.1.1.1','30.1.1.1', '40.1.1.1']  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign2' , ['10.1.1.1', '20.1.1.1', '50.1.1.1']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign3' , ['10.1.1.1', '40.1.1.1', '60.1.1.1', '70.1.1.1', '80.1.1.1']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser2', 'campaign4' , ['10.1.1.1', '20.1.1.1', '30.1.1.1']  
  
) select * from tbl_campaign_ipmapping
```

For an input advertiser lets say advertiser1 The logic to be implemented is depending
For each row retrieve the list of IP's and compare them with the IP's from all other rows(excluding the current row) and print the IP's that's not present.

So the expected output is

```
advertiser1, campaign1, ['50.0.0.0', '60.0.0.0', '70.0.0.0']
advertiser1,campaign2, ['30.0.0.0', '40.0.0.0', '60.0.0.0', '70.0.0.0']
advertiser1,campaign3, ['20.0.0.0','30.0.0.0', '50.0.0.0' ]
advertiser1,campaign4, ['40.0.0.0', '50.0.0.0', '60.0.0.0', '70.0.0.0'
```

Actually I don't need the array just the count. Just listed the array in the above output to clarify the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try below version - I feel it should be more optimal then previous ones

```
with advertiser_campaign_ip as (
  select advertiser, campaign, ip
  from (
    select advertiser, ip
    from tbl_campaign_ipmapping, unnest(ip_array) ip
    group by advertiser, ip
  ) join (
    select advertiser, campaign
    from tbl_campaign_ipmapping
  )
  using (advertiser)
)
select a.advertiser, a.campaign, 
  array_agg(a.ip) as missing_ip
from advertiser_campaign_ip a
left join (select advertiser, campaign, ip from tbl_campaign_ipmapping, unnest(ip_array) ip) b
using (advertiser, campaign, ip)
where b.ip is null
group by a.advertiser, a.campaign
```

Comment: have you tried this version?

Answer (score 0):

You may try utilizing another CTE to find all possible IPs before using this list to gather all other ips not apart of the current ip array eg

```sql
WITH tbl_campaign_ipmapping AS
(
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign1' as campaign,  ['10.0.0.0','20.0.0.0','30.0.0.0', '40.0.0.0'] AS ip_array UNION ALL
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign2' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '20.0.0.0', '50.0.0.0']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign3' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '40.0.0.0', '60.0.0.0', '70.0.0.0', '80.0.0.0']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign4' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '20.0.0.0', '30.0.0.0'] UNION ALL 
  
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign1' ,  ['10.1.1.1','20.1.1.1','30.1.1.1', '40.1.1.1']  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign2' , ['10.1.1.1', '20.1.1.1', '50.1.1.1']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign3' , ['10.1.1.1', '40.1.1.1', '60.1.1.1', '70.1.1.1', '80.1.1.1']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser2', 'campaign4' , ['10.1.1.1', '20.1.1.1', '30.1.1.1']  
  
),
all_ips AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ip 
    FROM tbl_campaign_ipmapping, unnest(ip_array) ip
    WHERE advertiser='advertiser1'
)
select 
    advertiser ,
    campaign,
    ARRAY(
        SELECT i.ip 
        FROM all_ips i 
        WHERE i.ip NOT IN (
                  SELECT ipa FROM UNNEST(t.ip_array) ipa
        )
    ) as other_ips
from 
    tbl_campaign_ipmapping t
WHERE advertiser='advertiser1'
```

or joining on a table of all possible ips (you may also consider materializing all_ips) eg

```sql
WITH tbl_campaign_ipmapping AS
(
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign1' as campaign,  ['10.0.0.0','20.0.0.0','30.0.0.0', '40.0.0.0'] AS ip_array UNION ALL
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign2' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '20.0.0.0', '50.0.0.0']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign3' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '40.0.0.0', '60.0.0.0', '70.0.0.0', '80.0.0.0']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign4' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '20.0.0.0', '30.0.0.0'] UNION ALL 
  
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign1' ,  ['10.1.1.1','20.1.1.1','30.1.1.1', '40.1.1.1']  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign2' , ['10.1.1.1', '20.1.1.1', '50.1.1.1']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign3' , ['10.1.1.1', '40.1.1.1', '60.1.1.1', '70.1.1.1', '80.1.1.1']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser2', 'campaign4' , ['10.1.1.1', '20.1.1.1', '30.1.1.1']  
  
),
all_ips AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ip 
    FROM tbl_campaign_ipmapping, unnest(ip_array) ip
    WHERE advertiser='advertiser1'
)
select 
    advertiser,
    campaign,
    ARRAY_AGG(i.ip) as other_ips
from 
    tbl_campaign_ipmapping t
inner join 
    all_ips i on i.ip NOT IN UNNEST(t.ip_array)
WHERE advertiser='advertiser1'
group by 
    advertiser,campaign
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thank you. This works but I had simplified the problem, there is an additional column advertiser and we need to filter for a specific advertiser only. I modified the logic with the same but running into  "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN."

Comment: Please update the question with your sample data and query attempt that is giving this error message

Comment: @ShivakumarGokaram I've updated the answer to match your sample and results shared. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you. The sample works perfectly fine with both the options you provided. I extended the same with few more columns to mimic my table I,e added 2 more fields key and an date field and its all good.   The issue I am facing is

Comment: When I try to run the same query on my actual tables then for the first method I get "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated.." I am trying to find the differences in the table definition I provided in above sample to my original tables. The only thing is the number of rows I have is about 600+ and the Distinct IP's is huge about 70K. So not sure if google BQ query optimizer deals this differently.

Comment: With the join method its takes a very long time 1min and also the values reported does not seem to be correct.  I am aware that I keep moving the goal and adding more to my requirement, I tried to simplify but did not expect that would cause so many issues.  I appreciate all your help here

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
with advertiser_ips as (
  select advertiser, array_agg(distinct ip) ip_array 
  from tbl_campaign_ipmapping, unnest(ip_array) ip
  group by advertiser
)
select advertiser, campaign,
  array( select distinct ip
    from b.ip_array ip
    where not ip in unnest(a.ip_array) 
  ) as missing_ip
from tbl_campaign_ipmapping a
join advertiser_ips b
using(advertiser)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: thank you for the alternate approach.  With the table size of 600+ rows and total distinct IP's of 70K this takes for ever to complete.  I had to cancel the query as it surpassed 2mins.

Comment: I just need the Count of IP's for each row that's not found. I don't even need the list of IP's eg:  advertiser1, campaign1, 4 which is the total count of elements in the array

Comment: @ShivakumarGokaram how about covering array inside array_length func. Like this ````array_length(array( select distinct ip
    from b.ip_array ip
    where not ip in unnest(a.ip_array) 
  )) as missing_ip````

Comment: The array length is fine and that will work the issue is time for query, since I have a lot of IP's this join is taking a very long time

Answer (score 0):

Try This. Not sure if this is optimized way, But I tried using SET operators

```
  WITH tbl_campaign_ipmapping AS
(
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign1' as campaign,  ['10.0.0.0','20.0.0.0','30.0.0.0', '40.0.0.0'] AS ip_array UNION ALL
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign2' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '20.0.0.0', '50.0.0.0']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign3' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '40.0.0.0', '60.0.0.0', '70.0.0.0', '80.0.0.0']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser1' as advertiser, 'campaign4' as campaign, ['10.0.0.0', '20.0.0.0', '30.0.0.0'] UNION ALL 
  
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign1' ,  ['10.1.1.1','20.1.1.1','30.1.1.1', '40.1.1.1']  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign2' , ['10.1.1.1', '20.1.1.1', '50.1.1.1']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser2' , 'campaign3' , ['10.1.1.1', '40.1.1.1', '60.1.1.1', '70.1.1.1', '80.1.1.1']  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'advertiser2', 'campaign4' , ['10.1.1.1', '20.1.1.1', '30.1.1.1']  
  
),
advertiser_all_ip as
(
select advertiser ,array_concat_agg(ip_array ) as all_ips
 from tbl_campaign_ipmapping
 group by advertiser 
),cte as (
select tci.advertiser ,campaign ,ip_array  , all_ips
from tbl_campaign_ipmapping tci
join advertiser_all_ip aaip
on tci.advertiser  = aaip.advertiser
)
select advertiser ,campaign,array_length(array_agg(arr))  as distinct_count
from (
    select advertiser ,campaign,arr  from cte,unnest(all_ips) as arr
    except distinct 
    select advertiser ,campaign,arr  from cte,unnest(ip_array) as arr
)
group by advertiser ,campaign
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the query. But due to large IP's this is not performing well.